# Aurelia unwanted letters appearing in text input after number format convert.

Tags: aurelia

I have a text input for a card number. It should only contain numbers and has to be shown to the user as 4-digit blocks (example: 1234 5678 9123 4567).
My code successfully removes entered letters and creates the number blocks. The problem is that when I type a single non-digit key two times, that key shows up in the input once, seemingly ignoring the value converter. This does not happen when trying to type different letters in a row. Any third input will delete the letter as it should, but the problem does not disappear.
Using console.log, I can see that toView always returns the correct value. Is there any way to fix this? I tried adding ' pattern="^[\d ]*$" ' to the input but that does literally nothing.

 Examples at the bottom.

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="cardNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="1234 5678 9123 4567"
                           value.bind="cardNumber | cardNumberFormat & validate" disabled.bind="isDisabled">
```

Javascript:

```
export class CardNumberFormatValueConverter {
      toView(value) {
        let cardNumberBlocks = this.createCardNumberBlocks(value);
        if (cardNumberBlocks) {
          return cardNumberBlocks.join(" ");
        }
        return "";
      }

      fromView(value) {
        return value.split(" ").join("");
      }

      createCardNumberBlocks(value) {
        if (!value) return "";
        return value.match(/\d{1,4}/g);
      }
    }
```

Examples:
Typing : 123456 - Result : 1234 56 - Correct
Typing : 123456a - Result : 1234 56 - Correct
Typing : 123456a2 - Result : 1234 562 - Correct
Typing : 123456aa - Result : 1234 56a - **Wrong**
Typing : 123456aa2 - Result : 1234 562 - Correct
Typing : 123456ab - Result : 1234 56 - Correct
Typing : 123456aaa - Result : 1234 56 - Correct
Typing : 123456aba - Result : 1234 56 - Correct
Typing : 123456aa3bb - Result : 1234 563b - **Wrong**
Typing : 123456aabbb - Result : 1234 56b - **Wrong**

Comment: I think you have found a legitimate bug, I altered the code a bit but toview receives the correct string but the rendered view doesn't update, even with a signal/throttle.

Check out the gist here:
https://gist.run/?id=2b8d88e30b6d72fcd2655ef959063262

Comment: suggest opening a bug @ https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues